# How to remove time from dateTime in kunena1.7

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

I use kunena in my site and I want remove time from datetime in latest post by user in main page or in post page.
I delete `%H:%i` from its variable in language file but time is shown still.
How can I remove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit code of kunena core.
For example in this path:

```
components/com_kunena/template/yourTemplate/view/message.php
```

I edited this:

```
<span class="kmsgdate kmsgdate-left" title="<?php echo CKunenaTimeformat::showDate($this->msg->time, 'config_post_dateformat_hover') ?>">
<?php echo CKunenaTimeformat::showDate($this->msg->time, 'config_post_dateformat'); ?>
</span>
```

To:

```
<span class="kmsgdate kmsgdate-left" title="<?php echo CKunenaTimeformat::showDate($this->msg->time, 'config_post_dateformat_hover') ?>">
<?php 
     $dateTime = CKunenaTimeformat::showDate($this->msg->time, 'config_post_dateformat');
     $date = explode(" ", $dateTime);
     echo  $date[1]; 
?>
</span>
```

And just date will be shown.

Answer (score 0):

In the Joomla backend:

1. Go to the Kunena Configuration page
2. Go to the "**Frontend**" tab
3. There is a parameter called "**Message Time Format**" which you can set to "**hide**"

**Update:**

Having said that, I realised I am using Kunena 2.0.x which you should also do. So I recommend upgrading to the latest version of Kunena, which is still Joomla 1.5 compatible.

Comment: yeah this is working, but this solution remove Date and Time both! I want remove jast Time. Like this: Last Post By admin in 24/1/13 with no time! Thanks ...